# Appending result of function into a list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm calling a function within a function. I want it so that every time the function loops (4 instances) it adds the result to a list. In bad programmer terms, something like: for each instance of the loop, run function, add result to list and increment counter, and go again.

Can you help here?

```
def genDigit():
    import random
    digit = (random.randint(0, 9))
    print(digit)
    return

def genNumber():
    numList = list
    for counter in range(0,4):
    'from here on I need to finish the function
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I understand in english terms how I would go about finishing this.

Kind regards, 
JJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the digit in your function and then returning nothing, you should return the generated digit. You can then collect those in a list, and return that list. Finally, you print the result.

```
import random # import once

def genDigit():
    digit = random.randint(0, 9)
    return digit # return the digit

def genNumber():
    numList = list() # add missing ()
    for counter in range(0,4):
        numList.append(genDigit()) # add digits to list
    return numList # return the list

print(genNumber()) # now print the entire list
```

Or shorter:

```
def genDigit():
    return random.randint(0, 9)

def genNumber():
    return [genDigit() for c in range(4)]
```

Comment: thanks that does indeed help, however with the shorter version I'm trying to manipulate the 4 numbers in a program so I would need a list. All the second one does is return the value but I'm struggling to see how I can add this to a list!

Comment: @JJP This _is_ a list. It's called a "list comprehension" and is a bit shorter/more concise than the for loop. The result is the same. Of course, if you are doing more inside the loop than just adding values to the list, then the loop is the better option.

Comment: I see, thanks for this info. I'm not sure how to manipulate this however. For instance, I'm trying to write a small program which a user enters four digits and it will tell them if it's the same four digits that the program has randomly generated. One function utilises the list, by checking if entry is eg 4567 and the program's number is 4568 the output would be YYYN, hence I'm using the list here. With this type of list I can't see how I could write anything to manipulate that? Thanks!

Comment: @JJP It is _exactly the same type of list_, just another way to create it. What type of list did you expect to get? For comparing the list with the user's guess, just do something like `[a==b for a, b in zip(guess, correct)]`

Comment: not 100% sure what your code means as I am new to python but as long as its the same type of list that works for me :) Thanks for your time!